# Alexa Skill kit : The target Lambda application returned a failure response

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I created a simple Hello world  Alexa Skill as an AWS Lambda using Java based on https://github.com/amzn/alexa-skills-kit-java/tree/master/samples/src/main/java/helloworld.

But when I tried to test my lambda function it returned the following error

{

"errorMessage": "Error loading class helloworld.HelloWorldSpeechletRequestStreamHandler: com/amazon/speech/speechlet/lambda/SpeechletRequestStreamHandler",

"errorType": "class java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"

}

But the zip file which I uploaded consist of *HelloWorldSpeechletRequestStreamHandler*

Why is this error?

Comment: Did you zip the folder, or, the content in the folder? You need to zip the content within the folder and upload that.

Comment: I used this comment "mvn assembly:assembly -DdescriptorId=jar-with-dependencies package" to create the jar file after adding my application id @Bill